# Modifying BluetoothChat Sample, Force Closing

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, chat

I am attempting to modify the BluetoothChat sample application. I simply want to send a message by pressing a button, and then display the response in a text view. I know that the connection works properly, the app ran perfectly fine before, however when alter the program ever so slightly (in order to display the recieved messages in the the textview) if crashes the application. All of the code is the exact same, and ive found out that this segment is what causes the program to crash, right after the connection is established

```
case MESSAGE_READ:
            Log.i(TAG, "READING");
            String readMessage = (String) msg.obj;

            //writeOutput(readMessage);

            break;
```

When i remove the call to the write output function the program runs perfectly...

```
public void writeOutput(String readmessage){

    //Recieves the string returned from the handler and displays it accordingly

    display.setText("");
    display.setText(readmessage);




}
```

Any Ideas? Here is my LogCat File as well

```
07-12 09:55:35.439: I/BluetoothChatService(17267): BEGIN mConnectedThread
-07-12 09:55:35.439: I/BluetoothChat(17267): MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: 3
-07-12 09:55:35.525: I/BluetoothChat(17267): READING
-07-12 09:55:35.525: D/AndroidRuntime(17267): Shutting down VM
-07-12 09:55:35.525: W/dalvikvm(17267): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception 
-07-12 09:55:35.525: E/AndroidRuntime(17267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
-07-12 09:55:35.525: E/AndroidRuntime(17267): java.lang.NullPointerException
-07-12 09:55:35.525: E/AndroidRuntime(17267):   at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat.writeOutput(BluetoothChat.java:344)
-07-12 09:55:35.525: E/AndroidRuntime(17267):   at com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat$1.handleMessage(BluetoothChat.java:255)
-07-12 09:55:35.525: E/AndroidRuntime(17267):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
-07-12 09:55:35.525: E/AndroidRuntime(17267):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
-07-12 09:55:35.525: E/AndroidRuntime(17267):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3906)
-07-12 09:55:35.525: E/AndroidRuntime(17267):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
-07-12 09:55:35.525: E/AndroidRuntime(17267):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
-07-12 09:55:35.525: E/AndroidRuntime(17267):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:840)
-07-12 09:55:35.525: E/AndroidRuntime(17267):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:598)
-07-12 09:55:35.525: E/AndroidRuntime(17267):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) -
```

Comment: paste your error stack too. Perhaps **display** is `null`

Comment: I'm sorry for the poor formatting, I'm trying to fix it

Comment: how are you initializing object `display`?

Comment: Wow...Thank you...I wasn't initializing the Text view. It's early and I haven't quite had my coffee, thank you for showing me to my ignorance HaHa :)